# View List from controller to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am just trying out stuff, I have items from different models and want to return them to as one(if its possible).
I have this ActionResult which returns all products from my database:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetAllContents()
    {
        ViewData["listy"] = GetColors();
        var i = (from p in db.tProducts
                select p).ToList();
        return View(i);
    }
```

and the list is coming from this method

```
  public List<SelectListItem> GetColors()
    {
        var listy = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var colorList = from a in db.tColors
                         select new SelectListItem
                         {
                             Text = a.id.ToString(),
                             Value = a.name
                         };
        foreach (var item in colorList)
            listy.Add(item);
        return listy;
    }
```

So how do I display this list as a dropdown on the View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use as below

```
@Html.DropDownList("listy", ViewData["listy"] as List<SelectListItem>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse your object to list of SelectListItem, you can use the following

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Colors, ViewData["listy"] as List<SelectListItem>, "-Colors-", new { })
```